# Difference between main Object into itk 4.8 toolkit

Tags: c++, object, itk

Anyone can help me to understand the difference among itk 4.8 data object. What are the difference between Vector Image, CovariantVector Image and Spatial Objects?

Answer (score 1):

The [`itk::VectorImage`](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1VectorImage.html) class is merely an image where each image pixel has a list of values associated with it rather than a single intensity value.

I am not aware of any `itk::CovariantVectorImage` class or a similar class.

The [`itk::Vector`](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1Vector.html) class represents a mathematical vector with magnitude and direction with operators and methods for vector addition, scalar multiplication, the inner product of two vectors, getting a vector's norm, and so forth. You can also perform linear transformations on them using methods in the [`itk::AffineTransform`](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1AffineTransform.html), mainly the `TransformVector()` method. This is not related to C++'s `std::vector` container object, which is really a dynamic array data structure.

The [`itk::CovariantVector`](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1CovariantVector.html) class is similar to `itk::Vector`, except it represents a *covector* rather than a *vector*. Covectors represent `n-1`-dimensional hyperplanes, (2D planes in the case of 3D space), and so their components transform in the opposite way that a vector's components do. `itk::AffineTransform`'s `TransformCovariantVector()` method will transform a `itk::CovariantVector` object according to covariant transformation laws.

The [`itk::SpatialObject`](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1SpatialObject.html) class allows you to create objects that exist in physical `n`-dimension space such as boxes, ellipses, tubes, planes, and cylinders, and relate these objects through parent-child relationships. You can read Chapter 5 of the [ITK software manual](http://www.itk.org/ItkSoftwareGuide.pdf) for more information on this topic.